# External windows mouse invert scroll except touchpad

Tags: mac, mouse, macos

I just attached an external windows mouse to my mac and I inverted the scrolling. But now it also inverts it for the touchpad... Is there a way to invert it only for the external mouse? I really don't want to switch it up every time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a simular issue as an inverted (external) mouse is pretty... **annoying**.
If you never use another computer, you will get used to it eventually.

But if you would like to customize buttons, I would recommend you [steermouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/) as per their site:

> SteerMouse is a mouse driver that lets you freely customize buttons,
>   wheels and cursor speed. Both USB and Bluetooth mice are supported, no
>   matter whether the mouse is designed for Windows or Mac.

Answer (score 1):

This is Apple redefining normal. For me it is fine on a trackpad but counter intuitive with a scroll wheel. It started on O/S X Lion and I have been using a little utility called Scroll Reverser to change the behavior:

https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/37872/scroll-reverser